# Reuse form in actions "New" and "Edit"

Tags: forms, templates, symfony, twig, page-title

I have actions "New" and "Edit". I want to reuse the same template in both actions. The problem is, when I'm creating a new entity, I want to show "New entity" in the page title. When I'm editing an entity I want to "Editing entity title".

I could pass a variable in each action indicating the action but I don't feel right doing it ... Are there any way to detect if it's a creation or edition in twig?

How would you solve this common issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the entity to the view and create a variable in twig

```
{% set isNew = not entity.id > 0 %}
```

easy?

if you want to pass only the form to the view you can get the entity directly from the form

```
{% set entity = form.get('value') %}
```

Comment: Or `{% if form.vars.value.id %}`